# Which Voyager spacecraft "mutinied", and what really happened?

Tags: nasa, spacecraft, voyager, mission-anomaly

The  August 2017 BBC News *Science in Action* podcast [The Algae that Changed the Earth](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/w3cstzrn) includes other topics, including the following:

> In August and September 1977, Nasa's probes Voyager 2 and Voyager 1 were launched. Since then the two spacecraft have been exploring our Solar System and interstellar space. Exceeding all expectations, the probes have taught us so much about our planets and beyond. **The Voyager mission's chief scientist, [Professor Ed Stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_C._Stone), looks back over Voyager's highlights.**

After about `10:00` in the podcast he says (rough, amateur transcription):

> **...and we did have sort-of a mutiny at the time when the spacecraft went off and did what its programs told it to do but not what we thought it should be doing.**
>
> And it took us several days to get things sorted out to realize that what had happened; the spacecraft is that it had been subjected to the effects of the launch vehicle which had not been taken into account in the initial software that the spacecraft had been given.
>
> But that all worked out and we were on our way to be ready for Jupiter which was less than two years away.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was Voyager 2 (launched before Voyager 1).

Technical details on Voyagers are surprisingly hard to find.  The most detailed account I found was in [Voyage to Jupiter](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19810002402.pdf), the official NASA history of the project.

> During  the   first   minutes  of   flight,  there seemed  to  be  two
>   difficulties  with  the  AACS.The  first  was  a  problem  with  one 
>   of  the  three stabilizing   gyroscopes,    but   fortunately,   the
>   gyroscope   began   operating  normally  without intervention  from 
>   the ground.  The  other  problem  appeared to  be with  one of the
>   AACS  computers;  the  spacecraft   switched  to  a   backup computer 
>   during  the  Titan  burn,  and   initial data    transmissions    were 
>   incomplete.   Early analysis seemed  to indicate that an event during
>   the launch itself,  rather  than  a  faulty spacecraft computer 
>   system,   was  the  cause  of  the  data loss.  At  first,  on  August
>   23,  officials  suspected that  perhaps  the  spacecraft  had  been 
>   bumped by  the  rocket  motor  one  hour  after  liftoff  and again about    seventeen   hours    later,    when telemetry  signals 
>   indicated  that  the  spacecraft had   been  jolted.  However,   by 
>   the  next  day, flight  engineers determined that electronic  gyrations
>   in  the  AACS  seemed  to  have  caused  the difficulty.

After describing other problems in the cruise phase, the book goes on to say

> In  general,  these  reactions  were  the result of programming too
>   much sensitivity into the  spacecraft  systems, resulting in  panic 
>   over-reaction  by  the  onboard  computers  to  minor fluctuations   in
>   the   environment.  Ultimately,part  of the programming had to be
>   rewritten on Earth  and  then transmitted to the  Voyagers,  to calm 
>   them   down   so  that   they  would  ignore minor  perturbations,  yet
>   still  be  ready  to perform  automatic  sequences  required  to 
>   protect the  spacecraft  from  major  threats.

AACS = Attitude and Articulation Control System

Comment: spacecraft-calming subroutines were introduced; "[voyager's little helper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother%27s_Little_Helper)"