# Is Perseverance still in Safe Mode?

Tags: mars, nasa, rovers, perseverance, mission-anomaly

Messages in [The Pod Bay](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55108705#55108705) and Space.com's [NASA: Mars rover Perseverance in 'safe mode' after launch, but should recover](https://www.space.com/mars-rover-perseverance-safe-mode-after-launch.html) both said that Perseverance was in "Safe Mode".

Is it still?

Comment: There was also an issue with the spacecraft being so close to Earth, that the signal was too strong for the DSN.  Apparently Perseverance is a [close talker](https://www.bingeclock.com/memes/seinfeld___define_close_talker.jpg).

Comment: @DrSheldon that's interesting; I can understand that in the very early part some antennas might not have enough range of attenuation, but  all one has to do is point the dish a little to one side to get any desired amount of attenuation. That might make [conical scanning](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/286062/102305) impossible or at least difficult, but with such a strong signal one could just use automated, computed pointing rather than active tracking. But I can't post a new question about it until you can confirm that you're pretty sure this was a real issue. Thanks!

Comment: The too-stong-signal is mentioned in the space.com article that you cite in this question.

Comment: @DrSheldon oh! okay I'll look tomorrow (it's 2 AM)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is Perseverance still in Safe Mode?

Not any more: [NASA's Mars rover Perseverance is fine and out of 'safe mode'](https://www.space.com/mars-rover-perseverance-is-fine-exits-safe-mode.html) as of July 31, 2020.

Answer (score 3):

It was as of the latest update, but they were working on recovering it. They have full communication with the spacecraft as of now. [The press release](https://mars.nasa.gov/news/8724/nasa-ula-launch-mars-2020-perseverance-rover-mission-to-red-planet/), issued on July 30, stated the following:

> Right now, the Mars 2020 mission is completing a full health assessment on the spacecraft and is working to return the spacecraft to a nominal configuration for its journey to Mars.

These things usually take a day or so. Bottom line is, there isn't a lot to worry about for now.

Comment: okay that's a relief, I was worried about it being another [spacecraft mutiny](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37828/12102)! ;-)